# partails html file changes not showing in angularjs app

Tags: html, angularjs

Hi i am working angularjs application code 
when i trying to update any value or field in js file i will show changes when i refresh browser but when i changes in  html file it is not slowing any changes

i am not sure it will work like js file or i need to do some thing deffenent

```
    <div ng-if="companyProfile.loansAndRatings[0].ratings != undefined" >
            <div class="panel-heading">Credit ratings</div>
            <hr class="loan-margin">
            <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered ">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Agency</th>
                        <th>Instrument</th>
                        <th>Instrument Details</th>
                        <th>Rating</th>
                        <th>Outlook</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="fontSynopsis">
                    <tr ng-repeat="creditRatings in companyProfile.loansAndRatings[0].ratings track by $index">
                        <td>{{creditRatings.agency}}</td>
                        <td>{{creditRatings.instrument}}</td>
                        <td>{{creditRatings.instrumentDetails}}</td>
                        <td>{{creditRatings.rating}}</td>
                        <td>{{creditRatings.outlook}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </div>
```

---

*When i update code and any value static value that not slowing after i refresh page*

```
<div ng-if="companyProfile.loansAndRatings[0].ratings != undefined" >
        <div class="panel-heading">Credit ratings</div>
        <hr class="loan-margin">
        <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Agency</th>
                    <th>Instrument</th>
                    <th>Instrument Details</th>
                    <th>Rating</th>
                    <th>Outlook</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="fontSynopsis">
                <tr ng-repeat="creditRatings in companyProfile.loansAndRatings[0].ratings track by $index">
                    <td>{{creditRatings.instrument}}</td>
                    <td>{{creditRatings.instrument}}</td>
                    <td>{{creditRatings.instrumentDetails}}</td>
                    <td>{{creditRatings.rating}}</td>
                    <td>{{creditRatings.outlook}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add the code where you are trying to change any values, probably in the controller.

Comment: i added where am changing if you have time to look i will give remote access to full application

Comment: Check `loansAndRatings` is not undefined also.

Comment: LoanRating is not undefind